Flutter Dart, Text fields printing the same thing, even though they have different controllers
Here's the page, as you can see, some special SizedBox do have different controller to handle different input from the user. However, when I write into the email or the password, or the password confirm, it prints as well into the two others, but it doesn't do that for the controller.name one. I have no clue how to fix it.
class SignUpController extends GetxController {
  static SignUpController get instance => Get.find();

  final email = TextEditingController();
  final password = TextEditingController();
  final name = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPassword = TextEditingController();

  void registerUser(String email, String password, String name) {
    AuthenticationRepository.instance.createUser(email, password, name);
  }
  @override
  void onClose() {
    email.dispose();
    password.dispose();
    name.dispose();
    confirmPassword.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}

class _AskIfCompanyState extends State<AskIfCompany> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool isJobSeeker = false;
  bool isCompany = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleCheckBoxChange(bool? selected, String type) {
    setState(() {
      if (type == 'jobSeeker') {
        isJobSeeker = selected ?? false;
        if (isJobSeeker) {
          isCompany = false;
        }
      } else if (type == 'company') {
        isCompany = selected ?? false;
        if (isCompany) {
          isJobSeeker = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void _requestFocus() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(SignUpController());


    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildLogo(screenWidth, screenHeight),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  const Text(
                    'Nom entier:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              SizedBox(
                child: buildTextField(
                  context: context,
                  controller: controller.name,
                  hinttext: 'Entrez votre nom et prénom',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  const Text(
                    'Email:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              SizedBox(
                child: buildTextField(
                  context: context,
                  controller: controller.email,
                  hinttext: 'Entrez votre mail',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  const Text(
                    'Mot de passe:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              SizedBox(
                child: buildTextFieldPassword(
                  context: context,
                  controller: controller.password,
                  hinttext: 'Entrez votre mot de passe',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  const Text(
                    'Confirmez votre mot de passe:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              SizedBox(
                child: buildTextFieldPassword(
                  controller: controller.confirmPassword,
                  context: context,
                  hinttext: 'Confirmez votre mot de passe',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  buildRoundCheckBox(
                    isChecked: isJobSeeker,
                    onChanged: (selected) =>
                        _handleCheckBoxChange(selected, 'jobSeeker'),
                    borderColor: const Color(0xffffd5c2),
                    checkedColor: const Color(0xffffd5c2),
                    uncheckedColor: Colors.grey[200] ?? Colors.grey,
                    checkedWidget: const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.black),
                    size: 24,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Je suis un candidat',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.15),
                  buildRoundCheckBox(
                    isChecked: isCompany,
                    onChanged: (selected) =>
                        _handleCheckBoxChange(selected, 'company'),
                    borderColor: const Color(0xffffd5c2),
                    checkedColor: const Color(0xffffd5c2),
                    uncheckedColor: Colors.grey[200] ?? Colors.grey,
                    checkedWidget: const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.black),
                    size: 24,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Je suis une entreprise (HR)',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  buildElevatedButton(
                    buttonText: 'S"inscrire',
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        SignUpController.instance.registerUser(
                          controller.email.text.trim(),
                          controller.password.text.trim(),
                          controller.name.text.trim(),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LogIn()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Déja un compte? Se connecter',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        height: 0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

I tried to retype the controllers but it didn't do anything, I asked chatGPT as well for more information about the misbehavior but it couldn't help me out much, so I'm stuck.

I found my issue, it was coming from the build function of the boxes actually!
